# How to specify raster name and how to designate the saved name of a created raster

Tags: arcpy, raster

```py
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
env.workspace = r"G:\GHY_568\project"

mystery_creek = r"G:\GHY_568\project\Mystery_Creek.shp"
riofajardo_stations = r"G:\GHY_568\project\riofajardo_stations.shp"    
gauge_station = r"G:\GHY_568\project\whiteoak_gauge.shp"    
dems = arcpy.ListDatasets("*_filled", "Raster")

#print dems    
#bethel_filled = r"G:\GHY_568\bethel_filled"    
#arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

for dem in dems:
    arcpy.env.extent = dem
    arcpy.env.cellSize = dem
    out_flow_direc = FlowDirection(dem)
    out_flow_acc = FlowAccumulation(dem)
##    if out_flow_acc > 200:
##        dem = 1
##    else:
##        dem = 0
    out_flow_length = FlowLength(out_flow_direc)
    out_cost_path = CostPath(gauge_station, out_flow_direc, out_flow_direc)
    if dem = "bethel_filled":
        out_watershed = Watershed(out_flow_direc, mystery_creek)
    else:
        out_watershed = Watershed(out_flow_direc, riofajardo_stations)
```

I need to specify which dem to use in the if statement and wasn't sure how to handle that, with "bethel_filled" in quotes or the path name or whath. Also the if statement at the end is in order to choose which dem to preform the watershed on because they have two different pourpoints. How do I specify which out_flow_direction to use in the if else statement. Mainly, how do I designate the saved name of each out_flow_direc.

Comment: If you look at the Code Sample section in the Help file for any of these tools you will see how to manipulate the rasters using python, including how to save them. At the moment you are referencing the rasters without actually making any of them permanent. At the end of this script you would technically have nothing to show as you never saved anything.

Comment: Look [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00p60000000r000000) for help with arcpy raster objects.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the first part of your question, you need to use the `==` equality operator rather than `=`.  Your list of DEMs also includes the extension, so you will need handle that.  For example, using the `==` operator, this is the syntax you would need to use:

```
# Sample list of DEMs
dems = ["test1.tif", "test2.tif", "bethel_filled.tif"]

for dem in dems:
    if dem == "bethel_filled.tif":
        print dem
```

Alternatively, you can add more flexibility to your conditional statement using the following syntax:

```
# Sample list of DEMs
dems = ["test1.tif", "test2.tif", "bethel_filled.tif"]

for dem in dems:
    if "bethel_filled" in dem:
        print dem
```

To answer the second part of your question: Spatial Analyst tools save raster data as raster objects, which can be useful for manipulating data using raster algebra.  However, saving the output is slightly different than other raster tools.

First, define the out workspace:

```
outws = r'C:\path\to\your\outws'
```

After you perform the watershed calcs, save the raster object to disk.  You will notice that `outname` is created using the `os.path.join()` function to join the outws and an output name.

```
out_watershed = Watershed(out_flow_direc, riofajardo_stations)
#out path and name
outname = os.path.join(outws, "out_watershed" + dem.split(".")[0] ".tif")
out_watershed.save(outname)
```

---

This is how it would all come together:

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
env.workspace = r"G:\GHY_568\project"
outws = r"G:\GHY_568\project\out" #You will need to add this folder

mystery_creek = r"G:\GHY_568\project\Mystery_Creek.shp"
riofajardo_stations = r"G:\GHY_568\project\riofajardo_stations.shp"
gauge_station = r"G:\GHY_568\project\whiteoak_gauge.shp"
dems = arcpy.ListDatasets("*_filled", "Raster")

for dem in dems:
    arcpy.env.extent = dem
    arcpy.env.cellSize = dem
    out_flow_direc = FlowDirection(dem)
    out_flow_acc = FlowAccumulation(dem)

    out_flow_length = FlowLength(out_flow_direc)
    out_cost_path = CostPath(gauge_station, out_flow_direc, out_flow_direc)
    if "bethel_filled" in dem:
        out_watershed = Watershed(out_flow_direc, mystery_creek)
        outname = os.path.join(outws, "out_watershed_condition1_" + dem.split(".")[0] + ".tif")
        out_watershed.save(outname)
    else:
        out_watershed = Watershed(out_flow_direc, riofajardo_stations)
        outname = os.path.join(outws, "out_watershed_condition2_" + dem.split(".")[0] + ".tif")
        out_watershed.save(outname)
```

Comment: It now gives me this error:
ExecuteError: ERROR 010214: Unable to read STA of g:\ghy_568\project\flowdir_beth1.
ERROR 010067:Error in executing grid expression.
Failed to execute (CostPath).

Comment: Most likely the format you are saving it as is an ESRI raster and in that case your file name is invalid. If you want to keep the name you have then you need to save it in another format, try tagging it with ".tif"?

Comment: @jaw485  The following is the help section on your error.  They provide several potential fixes. http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00vq0000000p010214